# JQuery Click event is not working in Firefox and Safari Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I need to place annotations mark for image, when user click on each annotations need to display a corresponding annotation message for the image.

It is working fine in chrome browsers both Mobile (IOS and Android) and Desktop  but not working in Safari and Firefox browsers in both mobile and desktop.

**script**

```
$('.announation').each(function(i) {
$('.announation').eq(i).on('click touchstart', function(e) {
                $(
                    '.one,.two,.three,.four,.five,.six,.seven,.eight,.nine,.ten,.ele'
                ).eq(i).css({
                    top: 0,
                    left: document.getElementById(e.srcElement.id).offsetLeft - 380
                }).show();
                document.getElementById(e.srcElement.id).innerText = "x";
                $('#' + e.srcElement.id).addClass("active");
            });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="annotationsmark">
    <div class="announation" alt="one" id="oneA">+</div>
    <div class="announation" alt="two" id="twoA">+</div>
    </div>

    <div id="messages">
         <div class="one">One</div>
         <div class="two">two</div>
    </div>
```

I tried Multiple ways :

Didn't work:

```
$(document.body).on( "click touchstart", ".announation", function() { });
```

Didn't work:

```
$('body .announation').eq(i).on('click touchstart', function(e){});
```

Didn't work:

```
$('.annotationsmark').on('click', '.announation', function(e) {
var i=$(this).index();
});
```

Comment: did you try $(".annotationsmark .announation").click(function(){})

Comment: Did you tried `this` instead of `document.getElementById(e.srcElement.id)`?

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be because of `srcElement`.Firefox & Safari may not support this.
Try replacing `srcElement` with `target` that is `e.srcElement.id` with `e.target.id`

Alternatively you can create a variable and use that variable

var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

Comment: In safari and firefox i cant able to trigger click events

Comment: @CodeMan inside the event listener put a debugger and please check

Comment: yes i tried 'debugger' sometimes it is triggering but most of times not triggering .